# How to optimize large database query accessed with an item ID?

Tags: sql, postgresql, nosql

I'm making a site that stores a large amount of data (8 data points for 313 item_ids every 10 seconds over 24 hr) and I serve that data to users on demand. The request is supplied with an item ID with which I query the database with something along the lines of `SELECT * FROM current_day_data WHERE item_id = <supplied ID>` (assuming the id is valid).

```sql
CREATE TABLE current_day_data (
    "time" bigint,
    item_id text NOT NULL,
    -- some data,
    id integer NOT NULL
);
CREATE INDEX item_id_lookup ON public.current_day_data USING btree (item_id);
```

This works fine, but the request takes about a third of a second, so I'm looking into either other database options to help optimize this, or some way to optimize the query itself.

My current setup is a PostgreSQL database with an index on the item ID column, but I feel like there's options in the realm of NoSQL (an area I'm unfamiliar with) due to it's similarity to a hash table.

My ideal solution would be a hash table with the item IDs as the key and the data as a JSON-like object but I don't know what options could achieve that.

tl;dr how to optimize `SELECT * FROM current_day_data WHERE item_id = <supplied ID>` through better querying or new database solution?

edit: here's the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) SELECT * FROM current_day_data`

```sql
                                                         QUERY PLAN
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on current_day_data  (cost=0.00..46811.09 rows=2584364 width=75) (actual time=0.013..291.667 rows=2700251 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=39058
 Planning:
   Buffers: shared hit=112
 Planning Time: 0.584 ms
 Execution Time: 446.622 ms
(6 rows)
```

EXPLAIN with a specified item id `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) SELECT * FROM current_day_data WHERE item_id = 'SUGAR_CANE';`

```sql
                                                          QUERY PLAN
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on current_day_info  (cost=33.40..12099.27 rows=8592 width=75) (actual time=2.949..12.236 rows=8627 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: (product_id = 'SUGAR_CANE'::text)
   Heap Blocks: exact=8570
   Buffers: shared hit=8619
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on prod_id_lookup  (cost=0.00..32.97 rows=8592 width=0) (actual time=1.751..1.751 rows=8665 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (product_id = 'SUGAR_CANE'::text)
         Buffers: shared hit=12
 Planning:
   Buffers: shared hit=68
 Planning Time: 0.339 ms
 Execution Time: 12.686 ms
(11 rows)
```

Now this says 12.7ms which makes me think the 300ms has something to do with the library I'm using (SQLAlchemy), but that wouldn't really make sense since it's a popular library. More specifically, the line I'm using is:
`results = CurrentDayData.query.filter(CurrentDayData.item_id == item_id).all()`

Comment: That can never take 300 milliseconds unless a) the index is in a very bad condition or b) the number of rows retrieved is large or c) your client has a problem displaying the result set. For a more detailed analysis, please provide the result of `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) SELECT ...`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe updated original post

Comment: Thanks. Yes, this query really only takes 12 milliseconds. Two possible explanations for the query time you observe: a) SQLAlchemy is actually executing a different query - activate logging in PostgreSQL and find the query in the log file b) your client takes a long time to render the 8627 result rows (not unheard of).

Answer (score 0):

That’s a very simple query that uses an index, therefore the only way to possible speed it up would be to improve the specification of your hardware.

Moving to a different form of database, on the same hardware, is not going to make a significant difference in performance to this type of query.